# Attempt to lookup non-existant entry: uid=dhruv@xyz.com,ou=users,o=xyz,dc=xyz,dc=com:

Tags: ldap, shiro

I am getting the below exception while trying to authenticate user from LDAP.

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: Attempt to lookup non-existant entry: uid=dhruv@xyz.com,ou=users,o=xyz,dc=xyz,dc=com:
org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapNoSuchObjectException: Attempt to lookup non-existant entry: uid=dhruv@idfc.com,ou=users,o=novopay,dc=novopay,dc=com
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.shared.partition.DefaultPartitionNexus.lookup(DefaultPartitionNexus.java:460)
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.authn.AuthenticationInterceptor.bind(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:568)
    at org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultOperationManager.bind(DefaultOperationManager.java:439)
    at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.request.BindRequestHandler.handleSimpleAuth(BindRequestHandler.java:184)
    at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.request.BindRequestHandler.handle(BindRequestHandler.java:636)
    at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.request.BindRequestHandler.handle(BindRequestHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.LdapRequestHandler.handleMessage(LdapRequestHandler.java:193)
    at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.LdapRequestHandler.handleMessage(LdapRequestHandler.java:56)
    at org.apache.mina.handler.demux.DemuxingIoHandler.messageReceived(DemuxingIoHandler.java:221)
    at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapProtocolHandler.messageReceived(LdapProtocolHandler.java:217)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:854)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:943)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:74)
    at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:475)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:429)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


BindRequest = 
MessageType : BIND_REQUEST
Message ID : 1
    BindRequest
        Version : '3'
        Name : 'uid=dhruv@idfc.com,ou=users,o=novopay,dc=novopay,dc=com'
        Simple authentication : '(omitted-for-safety)'
]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3087) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3033) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2835) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2749) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:153) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapContextFactory.createLdapContext(JndiLdapContextFactory.java:508) ~[shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapContextFactory.getLdapContext(JndiLdapContextFactory.java:495) ~[shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm.queryForAuthenticationInfo(JndiLdapRealm.java:375) ~[shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at in.novopay.webapp.portal.core.security.realm.AppRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(AppRealm.java:139) ~[AppRealm.class:na]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at in.novopay.webapp.portal.user.AuthenticationController.login(AuthenticationController.java:162) [AuthenticationController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at in.novopay.utils.web.filter.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:18) [web-utils-1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReport`enter code here`Valve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.61]
    at enter code hereorg.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.61]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.61]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

Comment: It appears, in the bind request, either the user: uid=dhruv@idfc.com,ou=users,o=novopay,dc=novopay,dc=com does not exist or the password is incorrect. You may want to show some code and provide an explanation as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it was giving problem with shiro so used diffrent solution, I haved added a code which uses jndi and performs ldap look up reference https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/3.1-authentication-options.html

and then based on the authentication from this code i have created session in shiro.